# Is The Perl Journal available online?

Tags: perl

Does anyone know where online copies of the old *The Perl Journal* articles can be found?

I know they are now owned by Dr. Dobb's, just the main page for it says they are part of whatever section the subject matter is relevant too, rather than being indexed together. That said, I have never been able to find any of them online on that site.

I know Mark Jason Dominus has a few of his articles [on his site](http://perl.plover.com/), any one know of any other good places? Or even what search terms to use at Dr. Dobb's?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Volumes 1-5 (1996 -> 2000) can be found at http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/

Hmm, looks like that was the entire run?  I though it was longer than that for some reason.

Comment: That was the entire run under Readable Publications and most of the way through the Earthweb years. CMP picked it up after that.

Answer (score 17):

Many of the articles have the string "TPJ" at the end of the article, so I get [quite a few results from searching just "TPJ"](http://www.ddj.com/TechSearch/searchResults.jhtml?queryText=TPJ&x=0&y=0). I'll put together [an index of the articles they published on the website](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=711609). Are you looking for a particular article or author?

I've linked to my TPJ Online articles on [my personal web page](http://www.pair.com/comdog), but they are all into the DDJ site with unhelpful URLs. Stonehenge gives out [Randal's TPJ articles for free](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/PerlJournal/), and Simon Cozens has [most of his articles online](http://simon-cozens.org/programmer/writing.html) too.

Besides the online articles, there are compilation books from O'Reilly Media: [Web, Graphics & Perl TK: Best of The Perl Journal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003110), [Games, Diversions & Perl Culture: Best of The Perl Journal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003129) , and [Computer Science & Perl Programming: Best of TPJ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003102) .

The issues at http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/ are the entire run of TPJ before it was purchased by Earthweb. At issue 20, [things got ugly as Earthweb was imploding in the dot.bomb days](http://lists.netisland.net/archives/phlpm/phlpm-2001/msg00005.html) and TPJ was eventually [bought by CMP and added a supplement to SysAdmin in the summer of 2001](http://ubmtechnology.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=43&item=343). That lasted for about a year before they let it die quietly, then it came back a couple years later as an online magazine. It finally stopped in 2006 when it was rolled into DDJ completely and ceased to exist as a title.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the 'TPJ' thing, but it makes a lot of sense in retrospect. Then again, it is the kind of question I am sure people wonder, so it is probably useful as a question.

Comment: The title for the second O'Reilly compilation is wrong there (though the link is correct).

Comment: @ysth @brian - fixed the 2nd link's title

Answer (score 8):

Randal Schwartz's Perl Journal articles are linked from http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/PerlJournal/

Comment: They are also available in a book called Randal Schwartz's Perls of Wisdom by Apress (ISBN 1-59059-323-5), which also has articles he wrote for Web Techniques, Linux Magazine and SysAdmin.